# Как отправить запрос при помощи requests, аналогичный данному curl

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl

Здравствуйте.

Есть такой `curl`

```
curl "http://ortc-developers-useast1-s0001.realtime.co/send" --data "AK=K4xqxB&AT=SomeToken&C=channel-98dc87e2-f424-4984-3bbd-b4a6aeeb0aa0&M=12345678_1-1_Some text"
```

И он работает.

Не понимаю, как отправить аналогичный запрос при помощи requests.

```
import requests 

url = 'http://ortc-developers-useast1-s0001.realtime.co/send'

data = 'AK=K4xqxB&AT=SomeToken&C=channel-98dc87e2-f424-4984-3bbd-b4a6aeeb0aa0&M=12345678_1-1_Some text'

r = requests.get(url, data=data)

print(r)

<Response [404]>
```

Comment: Так не get, а post как минимум

Comment: @andreymal а почему пост?

Comment: @IgorSergeevich потому что см. справку curl про аргумент `--data` и потому что отправлять данные через get это нарушение стандарта http и бред)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, сорян, с курлом особо не работал :) Однако все равно используется в гет, если это выборка а не изменение, так вроде правилам не противоречит

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
data = {'AK': 'K4xqxB',
        'AT': 'SomeToken',
        'C': 'channel-98dc87e2-f424-4984-3bbd-b4a6aeeb0aa0'
        'M': '12345678_1-1_Some text'}

r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

почитайте `data from url encoding` или как-то так

И еще должно так работать:

```
r = requests.post('http://ortc-developers-useast1-s0001.realtime.co/send/?AK=K4xqxB&AT=SomeToken&C=channel-98dc87e2-f424-4984-3bbd-b4a6aeeb0aa0&M=12345678_1-1_Some text')
```

Comment: Почему то post возвращает 401, а get 404

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik По-хорошему надо достать документацию, проверьте Ваши параметры, все ли там привильно указано?

Comment: @Sergeevich но почему-то curl возвращает нужный результат.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik: посмотрите, что сurl посылает. Сравните с `requests.post(url, data)` (wireshark, proxy). За исключением User-Agent и может быть Connection заголовков, данные идентичны. Если сервер явно User-Agent, проверяет, то попробуйте: `headers={'User-Agent': 'curl'}`. Проверьте, есть ли перенаправления `r.history`.